# How to connect java to ms access

Tags: java

i am having windows 10 64 bit java 64 bit ms access 64 bit.not i want to connect to java to ms access with jdbc odbc than it show that can not found driver .i do all the task for this but i can not found that driver in my lappi. please anybody help me.

my code is

```
import java.sql.*;

class driver 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    try
    {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");  

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Unable to load driver");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

and error is:-

[Crash log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwopK.jpg)

Comment: send your error as a text

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions - class names start with a capital letter, e.g. `Driver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jdbc odbc driver was removed in [Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html) (from the linked Java 7 tech guide) *The JDBC-ODBC Bridge should be considered a transitional solution; it will be removed in JDK 8. In addition, Oracle does not support the JDBC-ODBC Bridge. Oracle recommends that you use JDBC drivers provided by the vendor of your database instead of the JDBC-ODBC Bridge.* You *can* use [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) instead.

Comment: but i am using java 1.6 than also show that same driver problem

Comment: @sumitsolanki Where did you find a 64-bit Java 1.6 that runs on Windows 10? Java 1.6 is **twelve** years old! Oh, and you have a 64-bit version of access - correct?

Comment: yes i use 64 bit version of access .so what i do for the connect java to that access??